# error: `LHASH' was not declared in this scope,

Tags: c++, openssl

While upgrading OpenSSL from .97e to 1.0.2d I'm facing these errors,

> BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp: At global scope:
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error:
>   `X509*CBasicAuthCertificateLoader::GetCert' is not a static member of`
>   class CBasicAuthCertificateLoader'
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error: `LHASH' was not declared in
>   this scope BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error:`conf' was not
>   declared in this scope BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error:
>   expected primary-expression before '*' token
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error: `req' was not declared in
>   this scope BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error: expected
>   primary-expression before '*' token
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error:`issuer' was not declared
>   in this scope BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error: expected
>   primary-expression before '*' token
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error: `priv_key' was not declared
>   in this scope BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493: error: expected
>   primary-expression before "days" BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:494:
>   error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:494: error: expected`,' or `;' before
>   '{' token BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp: In member function`HRESULT
>   CBasicAuthCertificateLoader::GenerateCertificateData(char*, X509**,
>   EVP_PKEY**, PKCS12**)': BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:651: error:
>   `LHASH' was not declared in this scope
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:651: error:`conf' was not declared in
>   this scope BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:674: warning: cast from
>   `const char*' to`void*' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
>   BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:691: error: `GetCert' was not declared
>   in this scope BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:705: error:`GetCert' was
>   not declared in this scope

Has any one faced similar errors?

Answer (score 0):

> error: `LHASH' was not declared in this scope...

Ensure the source file in question includes `lhash.h`:

```
#include <openssl/lhash.h>
```

Also see the [`lhash(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/lhash.html) man page.

If you are already including `lhash.h`, then your project is probably not set up correctly.

---

You should clear this error first since its the first one listed. These errors have a way of chaining themselves:

```
At global scope: BasicAuthCertificateLoader.cpp:493:
error: X509* CBasicAuthCertificateLoader::GetCert' is not a static member 
of class CBasicAuthCertificateLoader'
```